# Twitter Bootstrap - how to call function on tab activation?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm trying to show alert dialog on tab activation but it doesn't work:

```
$('#myTab').on('shown', function (e) {
alert('test')
})
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Are you including `bootstrap-tab.js` or is it part of your bootstrap.js file?

Comment: Assuming you are displaying tab via `clicking` on an `element`; you can simply use `click` instead of `shown` for the element that triggers to open the tab.

Comment: It's part of bootstrap.js

Answer (score 2):

In Twitter Bootstrap, there is an event that fires on tab show (`show.bs.tab`). Given the following tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

...here is the Javascript that you can use:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  alert(e.target); // activated tab
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap there is `active` class for activated elements. You can check for this class instead of `shown`. Something like this may work for you :

```
($('#myTab').hasClass('active'))
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. I need to react on event of activation, not to check the condition and wait actively.

Comment: it has `active` class immediately after you click. there are two ways to do this as i know : first `hasClass` method; the second one is you can use `click` event. So you can react when tab's trigger clicked.

Answer (score 0):

@alix is correct, you need to call the initialization *when the tab becomes active*. I have had this problem multiple times and keep forgetting this fact when implementing this functionality on a tabbed page.

Answer (score -2):

Hey first of all there is nothing wrong that i can see in your code. So probably there should be some issues with importing libraries. Anyways i would like to suggest you another way which i used extensively when building html/javascript applications.

I use [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) for handling the dynamic content, events and data. This is a really great framework and make lot of things much easier. And recently i was using this twitter bootstrap and it makes bootstrap more powerful.

For you are going to do check out this example. Probably you can learn this with few clicks.
[Knockout click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)